# sh script to run multiple files in multiple languages

Tags: shell-script, python, ruby

Is it possible to have an sh script that would run a python file, run a command ruby file and run a ruby sonicPI file?
What would this look like?

Thank you!
Adi

Comment: Could you clarify what the context/goal is? ie do you just want three scripts run in a row? or side-by-side? Do you want them run completely in the background where no output is visible?

Comment: sounds for me to run multi command one by one which is completely duplicated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
python /path/to/script.py
ruby /path/to/script.rb
ruby /path/to/otherscript.rb
```